# How to load custom powershell profile with single command

Tags: powershell

I have a shared computer for which I want to create a custom PowerShell profile that I can load with a simple command but which otherwise never gets sourced.

I tried adding a function like this to the main $profile:

```
function custom() {.  C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\custom_profile.ps1}
```

The idea was that I could just type the command `custom` and it would load my custom profile.

This doesn't work, because it does the sourcing inside the function scope, and all of the functions and aliases are lost when I leave that scope.

I *could* just execute the entire `.  C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\custom_profile.ps1` command, but I am looking for a way to do this with a single command.

If I were in bash, I'd just use something like `alias custom=".  C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\custom_profile.ps1"`, but Powershell's `alias` doesn't work that way.

How can I do this in PowerShell?

Comment: What is your "main $profile" set to in this instance?
I'm struggling to work out why you wouldn't just have a "C:\users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowershell\profile.ps1" - which would only execute for [username].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, change the file to a psm1 (a powershell module) and then :

```
Function custom { 
   if(-not Get-Module custom_profile){
       Import-Module 'C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\custom_profile.psm1' 
   } else {
       Remove-Module custom_profile
       Import-Module 'C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\custom_profile.psm1' 
   }
}
```

and then running

```
custom
```

will do what you want.

As noted in the comments you might need

```
Export-ModuleMember -Variable * -Function * -Alias *
```

if your module is supposed to export variables and aliases as well as functions.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. It will work when you do not change profile, if you work on it constantly (and profile is something you do work on regularly) you would have to remove-module ; import module constantly. For static scripts it is OK tho.

Comment: Yeah, that is more likely :) Good job. You don't need `if` tho... just do the reload always.

Comment: The problem there is, ofc, you have to follow module conventions (verbs etc.) or it will constantly warn you :)

Comment: -DisableNameChecking on the import-module will take care of convention deviations.
IMO the "if" is required - or Remove-Module will throw an error.

Comment: `-DisableNameChecking` will do. `remove-module -ea 0` will solve an error.

Comment: Also, you are polluting your module list this way with something not exactly a module...

Comment: You can get rid of the checking and remove code by simply doing `Import-Module <path> -Force`. That will always reload it.

Comment: @briantist - nifty - never thought of using -force for that.

Comment: Furthermore, this doesn't work right without extra things to export stuff. If your config contains only `$x =1` doing this wont work.

Comment: True - you need `Export-ModuleMember -Variable * -Function * -Alias *` at the end of the .psm1 to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be to just use a variable instead of a function.

In profile:

```
$custom = 'C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\custom_profile.ps1'
```

Interactively:

```
. $custom
```

Probably want to use a better name that's less likely to be overwritten, but same concept.

Comment: you can save 1 char `$` by making it a function.

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing right now, but I was hoping for a way to do it with a single command that didn't require any special characters (such as `.` or `$`).

Comment: @PortMan why is it important not to use `.` or `$`?

Comment: @briantist 1) Because it's much easier to type and b) Because I'm already accustomed to doing it that way on linux, and I'd like to use the same command on both systems to load my custom profile.

Comment: I totally understand :)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be to use [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine), define your own handler to be executed, such as F5 to load custom prifile.

This is shorter then writing a command also as you have to press 1 key.

You should use PSReadLine anyway as it overpowers stock console in every aspect.